# undefined reference to `vtable for ClassName'

Tags: c++, qt, наследование

Возникли ошибки при компиляции. "qmake" ругается:

```
main.o: in function `gdbInterface::gdbInterface(QProcess):
undefined reference to `vtable for gdbInterface'
main.o: in function `gdbInterface::~gdbInterface()':
undefined reference to `vtable for gdbInterface'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Я так понимаю, что неправильно наследовал конструктор и деструктор.

Код:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>


class gdbInterface : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void onGDBConnected();

public:
    gdbInterface(QProcess &gdb);
};

void gdbInterface::onGDBConnected(){

}

gdbInterface::gdbInterface(QProcess &gdb){
    connect(&gdb, &QProcess::started, this , &gdbInterface::onGDBConnected);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QProcess gdb;
    QString gdbProgram;
    QStringList gdbArguments;

    gdbArguments << "-q"
                  << "/home/byeti/project/meerkat/meerkat_src/rat_lab"
                  ;//<< "--interpreter=mi";

    qint64* gdbPid = nullptr;

    gdbInterface interface(gdb);

    gdb.setProgram("gdb");
    gdb.setArguments(gdbArguments);
    gdb.startDetached(gdbPid);


    gdb.close();
    getchar();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно перегенерировать MOC файл и убедиться в том, что он участвует в компиляции вашего проекта.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Добавьте в самом конце файла, после закрывающей скобки:

```
#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Написанное по своим эффектам не отличается от кода в вопросе. Там точно так же вызывается дефолтный конструктор для базового `QObject`.

Comment: Разве конструктор по умолчанию предка вызывается сам? Подзабыл этот момент)

Comment: Да, дефолтный конструктор базового объекта может вызываться неявно.

Comment: Благодарю, сейчас подправлю

Comment: Sergey, Alexander, спасибо за советы. Сгенерировал main.moc файл, добавил его в проект, попробовал скомпилировать, появились две аналогичные ошибки: /usr/bin/ld: main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12gdbInterface[_ZTV12gdbInterface]+0x30): undefined reference to `gdbInterface::gdbInterface()'

Comment: Его не надо добавлять в проект, он генерируется автоматически qmake'ом. Вам видимо надо очистить проект и пересобрать

Comment: @ur_s ещё линковщик не видит определения методов класса, - их лучше перенести в объявления

Comment: Компилятор говорит, что не найден main.moc. Мне кажется, что он его ищет в папке с проектом, при этом qmake создаёт его в параллельно папке "debug-...".

Comment: Проверьте куда указывают пути сборки

Comment: А где можно посметреть пути? В ".pro"?

Comment: В закладке "Проекты" слева в QtCreator. Вы ведь в нем работаете, надеюсь?

Comment: Да, на CLion'e я бы не выдержал. В графическом представлении main.moc нет, а в Makefile есть.

Comment: main.moc создаётся qmake'ом и перед компиляцией, поэтому во время компиляции, соответственно, компилятор должен его видеть. В pro-файл его добавлять не надо. Проверьте пути, очистите и пересоберите проект

Comment: Alexander, я очень извиняюсь, но Qt Creater'ом пользуюсь второй день :) Вы не могли бы подсказать как это сделать? Вернее: что и где проверить; как отчищать проект; как именно пересобирать (через build или qmake)?

Comment: Если вы создали проект по умолчанию, то должно работать. Код должен выглядеть так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/231883/Зачем-подключают-moc-файлы-в-qt

Comment: Вам нужно перенести ваши определения методов в объявления. main.moc уже подхватывается

Comment: Вот, ещё лучше. Практически как у вас http://www.prog.org.ru/topic_24247_0.html